# Compressing a private key to fit into fixed size byte array

Tags: arrays, compression, private-key

I'm trying to compress a private key in the format of this [private key example](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/examples.html) as I need to fit it into a fixed size byte array (768 bytes to be exact). This is for a project with an RFID reader I'm working on.

Is there a way I can compress the private key as shown in the example down from around 820 bytes currently (removing the header and footer)?

I thought encoding it with base64 or something would help but it actually made it longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is already encoded in base64, so you can make it smaller by *decoding* the base64 to produce the original binary key. That key is 608 bytes.